# IFrame always showing above modal, how to make modal show on top

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, bootstrap-modal, fancybox

On my site we iframe in content from other pages (as the header needs to stay between pages with all it's content which is responsive). On clicking the burger icon, this loads up our Quick Links page which, as it suggests, loads up a navigation menu.

With the homepage, we also use modals to show certain lookups for certain clients content.

I'm using fancybox for the iframed content as below and then using Bootstrap modals to show the content however the iframe always displays above the modal. I've tried to get the iframe to close with a command on the onclick which triggers the modal however it's not working.

The iframe call:

```
<a data-fancybox data-type="iframe"  href="/SitePages/QuickLinks.aspx" target="iframe1" title="Load Quick Links" onclick=""><i class="fas fa-bars fa-2x" style="position:relative; top: 3px; left: -50px;"></i></a>
```

The Modal call:

```
<a class="dropdown-item text-dark" onclick="parent.flux(); " target="_blank"> Fluxed joints Lookup</a>
```

How can I either A) close the iframe when clicking "Fluxed Joints Lookup" or B) Display the modal above the frame.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Comment: Are you using facybox? if so you can call `fancybox.close();` in the onclick of "Fluxed Joints Lookup". https://fancyapps.com/docs/ui/fancybox/api

Comment: Unfortunately fancybox.close(); doesn't seem to be working and z index isn't working for this